# How to make GetLocaleInfoEx return its data in a specific language?

Tags: c++, winapi, locale

I'm using `GetLocaleInfoEx` to obtain the "display name" of a locale : however, I would like the "display name" to be returned in the language that's used in that locale.

The code amounts to this (`ex-MX` is used here as an example) :

```
const wchar_t localeName[] = L"es-MX";
wchar_t buf[1024];
GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName, LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME, buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf));
std::cout << to_utf8(buf) << '\n';
```

However, the returned string is

```
Hiszpański (Meksyk)
```

presumably because my system locale, and the display language, is set to Polish.

What can I do to force `GetLocaleInfoEx` to return the string in Spanish (in this particular case)? I would expect it to be something like

```
Español (México)
```

What I've tried so far (both things were done *before* calling `GetLocaleInfoEx`) :

1. Converting the locale name to a LCID and setting the thread locale :

```
SetThreadLocale(LocaleNameToLCID(localeName, 0));
```

2. Setting the preferred UI language :

```
const wchar_t preferredLangs[] = L"es-MX\0";
unsigned long numLangsSet;
SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, preferredLangs, &numLangsSet);
if (numLangsSet != 1) {
  return 1;
}
```

However, none of these methods seem to work : the returned string is still `Hiszpański (Meksyk)`.

What else can be done to set the desired language of `GetLocaleInfoEx`'s output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LOCALE_SNATIVEDISPLAYNAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-snative-constants) instead of `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME` iin your call to `GetLocaleInfoEx`.